non-negative constraints and interactions in the ensemble model
In the context of prediction problems using regression models, suppose I have $K$ different models all trained (fitted) on the same targets (observations). These models are different - low correlation between predictions in some sense. These models have been fitted separately instead of having a single big regression for practical reasons (each model is for a different dataset, each with 100s of features and specific modelling effort) and as way to reduce dimension as first step.
To fit the meta model (ensemble), I define a feature $f_k$ as the output for the regression model $k$. Since the targets are the same, the beta coefficient for $f_k$ should be positive on a univariate fit. Therefore, I am considering using Non-Negative Least Squares.  However, I wonder if this may not be unnecessarily constraining: jointly, perhaps I would expect most of the coefficients to be positive, but maybe not all.
Furthermore, I may have additional interaction features $g_j$ to include in the meta model that have no predictive power on their own (~0 coefficient) but could possibly be useful as interaction. As hypothetical example, dense clouds in presence of wind might predict rain, so I have a positive coefficient on cloud density but wind is purely an interaction term. Since I don't know the sign of the coefficients of the interactions (product between features and interactions $f_k g_j$), I could specify an optimisation where only the coefficients of the features $f_k$ have a positive constraints. Alternatively, I could fit NNLS on the products between bins of $g_j$ and features $f_k$.
Is there a good textbook or reference for this kind of meta-learning problem? This is a low signal-to-noise ratio problem, so I don't want to fit just any unconstrained regression model on the feature $f_k$.
For tree models, I see some implementations dealing with these issues. For example LGBM allows to specify which feature is monotonic (doesn't have to be all features), which features can interact, and a "penalty" parameter can relax the monotonicity constraints. A better method to enforce monotonic constraints in
regression and classification trees.
